# Does a refugee settled in Canada need a visa for France?

Tags: visas, canada, france, refugees

I have a permanent resident card of Canada and I do have a refugee travel document, Do i need a visa to travel to France and stay less then 30 days for vacation?

Comment: If you have lived in Canada for five years and been physically present for three years or more, you may be [eligible to naturalize](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/canadian-citizenship/become-canadian-citizen/eligibility.html) right away as a Canadian citizen. Then you can travel visa-free on a Canada passport to almost everywhere.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you need a visa.

France does not even participate on the multilateral European agreement on visa-free travel for refugees; Canadian refugee travel documents are right out.

(Note that whether *refugees* need visas is a point that is *not* harmonized at the Schengen level, so each member state sets its own rules. Still, if you get a visa, it will be a uniform short-stay Schengen visa giving access to the whole area, unless there's a particular reason to issue one with limitd territorial validity).